# GRPC/C++ - How to detect client disconnected in Async Server

Tags: c++, grpc

I am using the code of this [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.32.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc) to create my GRPC async server:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <grpc/support/log.h>

#ifdef BAZEL_BUILD
#include "examples/protos/helloworld.grpc.pb.h"
#else
#include "helloworld.grpc.pb.h"
#endif

using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::ServerCompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using helloworld::HelloRequest;
using helloworld::HelloReply;
using helloworld::Greeter;

class ServerImpl final {
 public:
  ~ServerImpl() {
    server_->Shutdown();
    // Always shutdown the completion queue after the server.
    cq_->Shutdown();
  }

  // There is no shutdown handling in this code.
  void Run() {
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");

    ServerBuilder builder;
    // Listen on the given address without any authentication mechanism.
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    // Register "service_" as the instance through which we'll communicate with
    // clients. In this case it corresponds to an *asynchronous* service.

    //LINES ADDED BY ME TO IMPLEMENT KEEPALIVE 
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS, 2000);
    builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT_MS, 3000);
    builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS, 1);
    //END OF LINES ADDED BY ME

    builder.RegisterService(&service_);
    // Get hold of the completion queue used for the asynchronous communication
    // with the gRPC runtime.
    cq_ = builder.AddCompletionQueue();
    // Finally assemble the server.
    server_ = builder.BuildAndStart();
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

    // Proceed to the server's main loop.
    HandleRpcs();
  }

 private:
  // Class encompasing the state and logic needed to serve a request.
  class CallData {
   public:
    // Take in the "service" instance (in this case representing an asynchronous
    // server) and the completion queue "cq" used for asynchronous communication
    // with the gRPC runtime.
    CallData(Greeter::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* cq)
        : service_(service), cq_(cq), responder_(&ctx_), status_(CREATE) {
      // Invoke the serving logic right away.
      Proceed();
    }

    void Proceed() {
      if (status_ == CREATE) {
        // Make this instance progress to the PROCESS state.
        status_ = PROCESS;

        // As part of the initial CREATE state, we *request* that the system
        // start processing SayHello requests. In this request, "this" acts are
        // the tag uniquely identifying the request (so that different CallData
        // instances can serve different requests concurrently), in this case
        // the memory address of this CallData instance.
        service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_,
                                  this);
      } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
        // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients while we process
        // the one for this CallData. The instance will deallocate itself as
        // part of its FINISH state.
        new CallData(service_, cq_);

        // The actual processing.
        std::string prefix("Hello ");
        reply_.set_message(prefix + request_.name());

        // And we are done! Let the gRPC runtime know we've finished, using the
        // memory address of this instance as the uniquely identifying tag for
        // the event.
        status_ = FINISH;
        responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
      } else {
        GPR_ASSERT(status_ == FINISH);
        // Once in the FINISH state, deallocate ourselves (CallData).
        delete this;
      }
    }

   private:
    // The means of communication with the gRPC runtime for an asynchronous
    // server.
    Greeter::AsyncService* service_;
    // The producer-consumer queue where for asynchronous server notifications.
    ServerCompletionQueue* cq_;
    // Context for the rpc, allowing to tweak aspects of it such as the use
    // of compression, authentication, as well as to send metadata back to the
    // client.
    ServerContext ctx_;

    // What we get from the client.
    HelloRequest request_;
    // What we send back to the client.
    HelloReply reply_;

    // The means to get back to the client.
    ServerAsyncResponseWriter<HelloReply> responder_;

    // Let's implement a tiny state machine with the following states.
    enum CallStatus { CREATE, PROCESS, FINISH };
    CallStatus status_;  // The current serving state.
  };

  // This can be run in multiple threads if needed.
  void HandleRpcs() {
    // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients.
    new CallData(&service_, cq_.get());
    void* tag;  // uniquely identifies a request.
    bool ok;
    while (true) {
      // Block waiting to read the next event from the completion queue. The
      // event is uniquely identified by its tag, which in this case is the
      // memory address of a CallData instance.
      // The return value of Next should always be checked. This return value
      // tells us whether there is any kind of event or cq_ is shutting down.
      GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
      GPR_ASSERT(ok);
      static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
    }
  }

  std::unique_ptr<ServerCompletionQueue> cq_;
  Greeter::AsyncService service_;
  std::unique_ptr<Server> server_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ServerImpl server;
  server.Run();

  return 0;
}
```

Because I've made a research and there I found out that I have to implement KeepAlive ( https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/md_doc_keepalive.html ) i've added those lines:

```
builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS, 2000);
builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT_MS, 3000);
builder.AddChannelArgument(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS, 1);
```

So far so good, server works and communication is flowing. However how can I detect that client has disconnected ? Lines I've added to make the so called `KeepAlive` method seems to not work for me.

Where is my mistake and how can I detect on a Async server when client has been disconnected by any reason?

Answer (score 8):

Let me start with a little background information.

One thing that's important to understand about gRPC is that it uses HTTP/2 to multiplex many streams on a single TCP connection.  Each gRPC call is a separate stream, regardless of whether the call is unary or streaming.  Generically speaking, any gRPC call can have zero or more messages sent from both sides; a unary call is just a special case that has exactly one message from the client to the server followed by exactly one message from the server to the client.

We generally use the word "disconnected" to refer to the TCP connection breaking, not to an individual stream terminating, although sometimes people use the word in the opposite sense.  I'm not sure which one you mean here, so I'll answer both.

The gRPC API exposes the stream lifecycle to the application, but it does not expose TCP connection lifecycle.  The intent is that the library handles all of the details of managing TCP connections and hides them from the application -- we don't actually expose a way to tell when a connection has dropped, and you shouldn't need to care, because the library will automatically reconnect for you. :)  The only case where this will be visible to the application is that if there are streams that are already in flight on an individual TCP connection when it fails, those streams will fail.

As I said, the library *does* expose the lifecycle of individual streams to the application; the lifetime of the stream is basically the lifetime of the `CallData` object in the code above.  There are two ways to find out if the stream has been terminated.  One is to explicitly call [`ServerContext::IsCancelled()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1_server_context_base.html#a8cddeac523cbcfb67113bfd39b70c148).  The other is to request an event on the CQ to asynchronously notify the application of cancellation via [`ServerContext::AsyncNotifyWhenDone()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1_server_context_base.html#a0f1289f31257e6dbef57bc901bd7b5f2).

Note that in general, unary examples like the HelloWorld one above don't really need to worry about detecting stream cancellation, since the entire stream doesn't really last very long from the server's perspective.  It's generally more useful in the case of a streaming call.  But there are some exceptions, such as if you have a unary call that has to do a lot of expensive asynchronous work before sending a response.

I hope this info is helpful.

Comment: Hey @Mark D. Roth! Thank you for your detailed answer. In bidi stream sync i tried `IsCanceled()` while I stop forcefully the streaming on the client and it seems to be not catched. See how I check for it here: https://gist.github.com/Armmegon/f524ab4765b005f5160beb1e2c0c6d3a

Comment: It looks like that example is using the syncronous API, and you're checking `IsCancelled()` only once, right after the request handler starts.  So what's probably happening here is that the `IsCancelled()` call is happening on the server before the server actually sees the cancellation from the client.  If you move the `IsCancelled()` check inside of the `while (stream->Read(&note))` loop, it should work.

Comment: The thing is even inside the loop it does not.

Comment: Your code appears to be checking `IsCancelled()` on `ctx_`.  I'm not sure what that object is, but the context you want to be checking is the one passed into the request handler method as `context`.