# C++/gRPC - IsCancelled not working properly

Tags: c++, grpc

I am using gRPC sync api with C++.

Here is how on server side I am checking if the client has stopped the stream.

```
grpc::Status AuthServer::ConnectServiceImpl::HearthBeat(grpc::ServerContext *context,
grpc::ServerReaderWriter<Pulse, Pulse> *stream) {
Pulse note;
if(ctx_.IsCancelled()){
std::cout << "DISCONNECT" << std::endl;
    }
while (stream->Read(&note)) {
Pulse reply;
reply.set_rate(note.rate()+1);
std::cout << "RECEIVED: " << note.rate() << std::endl;
stream->Write(reply);
}

return grpc::Status::OK;
}
```

This is bidi stream which is stopped forcefully on client side with killing the client app and still the "DISCONNECT" message does not appear.

Why is that, am I using `IsCancelled()` not correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I already answered this in [GRPC/C++ - How to detect client disconnected in Async Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297617/grpc-c-how-to-detect-client-disconnected-in-async-server).

Your code appears to be checking `IsCancelled()` on `ctx_`. I'm not sure what that object is, but the context you want to be checking is the one passed into the request handler method as `context`.