# AttributeError: 'grpc._cython.cygrpc._ServicerContext' object has no attribute 'add_done_callback'

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I am using grpc.aio.server(). My objective is to detect a client disconnect on the server side.

I'm trying to register a callback using the context on server side using add_done_callback(), but it does not seem it exposed for grpc._cython.cygrpc._ServicerContext

The documentation [here](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html#shared-context) mentions the callback, but I can't seem to be able to get it to work.
Note, if I use grpc.server() instead, I can set add_callback()

I'm using:
aiogrpc             1.8
grpcio              1.36.1
grpcio-tools        1.35.0

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you see this message here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297617/grpc-c-how-to-detect-client-disconnected-in-async-server

Comment: Thanks Casey. Indeed, I'm looking for something similar to the C++ ServerContext::AsyncNotifyWhenDone() but for python aio.. It seems its equivalent is not possible?

Comment: The only think I can think of (off the top of my head) would be to use some kind of asyncio/await functionality (many videos on You Tube on the topic)

It ~may~ help you. I had a similar problem. I would create an Order on an Exchange and wanted to get notification after the order was successfully executed. "Ping"ing the server every so many seconds could lock out an account. What I would up doing was subscribing to a User Data Stream Websocket for the Exchange instead (whereby the exchange server sent back notice when the task was completed).